# Git & Jenkins: get latest green commit on branch

Tags: jenkins, git, bitbucket, bcbsn

We're just starting to push for CI-CD and as a baby step we're going to try updating a stack with the latest green develop once every couple of hours. I am fairly new to Git/Bitbucket, and can't figure out how to ensure the checkout that Jenkins makes gets the last commit to have been marked green by Jenkins, rather than just "the last commit" as a blanket statement.

We have the [Bitbucket Build Status Notifier](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Cloud+Build+Status+Notifier+Plugin) plugin installed, so Bitbucket does track which commits are green after our unit tests run. Is there a way to leverage this info to make sure the right commit is picked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't make any mention of the scripting language you want to use, so I will talk specifically about the HTTP requests to the BitBucket API:

### Assumptions

If you have a [BitBucket Repository](https://bitbucket.org/RichardSlater/greencommitproofofconcept) that has three commits in in it the first and the last are failing the build, the middle is passing:

- 4768815 ❌
- 49d7110 ✅
- 42d357f ❌

### Get the list of commits

You can get the list of commits by calling the following API method:

> `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{{owner}}/{{repo_slug}}/commits`
>
> - `owner`: RichardSlater
> - `repo_slug`: greencommitproofofconcept

The response looks like this:

```
{
  "pagelen": 30,
  "values": [
    {
      "hash": "4768815fdc27abf4be17096e7c460f7f68f5d39b",
      "repository": { ... },
      "links": {
        ...
        "statuses": {
          "href": "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/RichardSlater/greencommitproofofconcept/commit/4768815fdc27abf4be17096e7c460f7f68f5d39b/statuses"
        }
      },
      "author": { ... },
      "parents": [ ... ],
      "date": "2017-04-10T11:38:18+00:00",
      "message": "README.md edited online with Bitbucket",
      "type": "commit"
    },
    {
      "hash": "49d7110b98616358d16055960a4abdf2926b890d",
      ...
    },
    {
      "hash": "42d357f1df7a7d7bcf1f10a9f3a5a40d85d5b11c",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

If you parse the JSON and loop over the responses you can extract out the statuses from:

```
values[n].links.statuses.href
```

Where `n` is the index, i.e. `0`, `1` or `2` in the above example.  If you were to construct this from scratch it would be in the following format.

### Get the list of statuses from the commit

> `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{{owner}}/{{repo_slug}}/commit/{{sha}}/statuses"`
>
> - `owner`: RichardSlater
> - `repo_slug`: greencommitproofofconcept
> - `sha`: 4768815fdc27abf4be17096e7c460f7f68f5d39b

**Note:** this is a Hypermedia API which means the urls *could* change so I would recommend using the links from the previous response rather than trying to generate them from scratch.

The response from the above HTTP request will be something like:

```
{
  "pagelen": 10,
  "values": [
    {
      "key": "POC-01",
      "name": "Build #1",
      "repository": { ... },
      "url": "http://devops.stackexchange.com/q/809/397",
      "links": { ... },
      "refname": null,
      "state": "FAILED",
      "created_on": "2017-04-10T13:04:28.261734+00:00",
      "updated_on": "2017-04-10T13:04:28.261759+00:00",
      "type": "build",
      "description": "Changes by Richard Slater"
    }
  ],
  "page": 1,
  "size": 1
}
```

From this response you can extract the `state` using:

```
values[n].state
```

Again where `n` is the `status` - there could be many of them if one commit resulted in many builds.

If the state for the build you care about is `SUCCESSFUL` then you have your answer and you can immediately return the `sha` for the commit.

Loop over all of the commits from the first phase, if you run out of commits follow the `next` page `link` that is included in the call to `/commits`.

### Complete Flow Diagram

At a high level the flow will look like this:

[image: Flow Diagram]

Don't forget this is a [Hypermedia API](https://looselyconnected.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/the-richardson-maturity-model-of-rest-and-roy-fielding/) so wherever possible have your code follow the links in the API rather than trying to "guess them".

Comment: Yes it does, it's probably my longest answer on SE ever.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to explain this even if you think I'm completely insane for wanting it. Accepted

Comment: Not completely insane, just taking your first few steps - keep my other answer in mind when you are thinking about CI/CD architectures.

Answer (score 3):

In a typical Continuous Delivery/Deployment pipeline you would have the following happen:

1. Developer pushes one or more commits, or, a pull request is merged.
2. Jenkins automatically builds and executes tests.
3. If successful Jenkins publishes a deployment package to an Artefact Repository; if failure publishes nothing and notify developers.
4. Deployment automation uses packages from the Artefact Repository and deploys them.

[image: Simple CI/CD Pipeline]

The goal is to avoid **building** the solution from source twice, you build it once and deploy it many times.  You can implement approvals in [Sonartype Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype) to define the environment approval process, i.e. Dev → Test → UAT → Stage → Production.

**That said...** if you have read all of the previous and still want to get the latest green build from source control then you can use one of two techniques:

1. Have Jenkins tag the branch with a suitably named tag, i.e. `master-green` then use that instead of `master` when you want the latest green build.
2. Use the BitBucket [commits](https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/tutorials/tutorials.bitbucket.org/commits) to get a list of commits and [commit/{sha}/statuses](https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/tutorials/tutorials.bitbucket.org/commit/f25983afbdd4d09811fe750d53d3ff7a857f941b/statuses) over each one to find the commit with a Green status.  I have expanded on this solution in [another answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/832/397).

Feel free to post a follow-up question if you would like the specific detail on how to use the above approaches.